# Extracting integers from a string of ordered pairs in Python?

Tags: python, tuples, sequence, split, iterable-unpacking

This may be super simple to a lot of you, but I can't seem to find much on it. I have an idea for it, but I feel like I'm doing way more than I should. I'm trying to read data from file in the format *(x1, x2) (y1, y2)*. My goal is to code a distance calculation using the values x1, x2, y1 and y2.

Question: How do I extract the integers from this string?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Could you give an example of the input data and the output you're looking for?

Comment: David: I'm trying to code a distance formula where I read a string from file, namely "(5, 42) (20, -32)", and I have to output the result. I'm just stomped on how to break that string of ordered pairs into a list of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with regex

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "(5, 42) (20, -32)"
>>> x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, re.match(r"\((.*), (.*)\) \((.*), (.*)\)", s).groups())
>>> x1, y1
(5, 42)
>>> x2, y2
(20, -32)
```

or without regex

```
>>> x1, y1, x2, y2 = (int(x.strip("(),")) for x in s.split())
```

Comment: Ah... That's more like it. Thanks!

Comment: @gnibbler - is that possible ("(),") in PHP?

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian, Python's `str.strip` is a bit unusual. I don't think there's such a simple way to do it in PHP. If you can't find a question about it, you could try creating one.

Comment: @gnibbler I just realized, this is possible in PHP.  If we strip the ()'s then explode by , or " ", and push it into list() = then we have a matching result.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and can be done like this

```
>>> a =(1,2)
>>> x1,x2=a
>>> x1
1
>>> x2
2
>>> b = [[1,2],[2,3]]
>>> (x1,x2),(y1,y2)=b
>>> x1
1
>>> x2
2
>>> y1
2
>>> y2
3
>>>
```

Comment: RT: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I'm reading in from file, so that ordered pair is read first as a string. I'm trying to break the string into integers that I can assign to vars.

Comment: @Stephen Paul, answer of gnibbler should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the values out of some lists and into variables this is one way to do it.

```
>>> x1, y1, x2, y2 = [1, 2] + [3, 4]
>>> x1
1
>>> x2
3
>>> y1
2
>>> y2
4
>>>
```

tuples will exhibit the same behavior.

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = (1, 2) + (3, 4)
```

Here is how to read the input out of a file and parse it using gnibbler's regular expression

```
import re

with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as file_handle:

    for line in file_handle:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, re.match(r"\((.*), (.*)\) \((.*), (.*)\)", line).groups())
        print x1, y1, x2, y2
```

Comment: Awesome. I've got it now. Thanks man!

Comment: Cool, also if you decide to keep using SO don't forget to ask really good questions =).

Comment: I'll be working on it! Thanks again.